# how to remove none at the end of my recursive function?

Tags: python

Could someone explain to me why this function at the end returns none and how to remove it thanks

```
def cuenta_regresiva(numero):
    if numero > 0:
         print(numero)
         cuenta_regresiva(numero-1)

print(cuenta_regresiva(5))
```

Comment: Absent any other return value, a function will return `None`, which is what you are returning. Since `cent_regresiva` is printing a value itself, and not returning one, there is no reason to call `print` outside the function.

Comment: `print(cuenta_regresiva(5))` -> `cuenta_regresiva(5)`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

because you are printing the returned result of the function.
and the result is None.

you should just call the function, and function print the numbers:

```
def cuenta_regresiva(numero):
    if numero > 0:
         print(numero)
         cuenta_regresiva(numero-1)

cuenta_regresiva(5)
```